# How to make multiple requests on flask server in Python?

Tags: python, flask

I've set up two flask servers on different ports (5000 & 5001). I'm sending a Http request from server 1 and getting a response from server 2. But when I make another request (this time from server 2), I'm getting the below error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5000): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /fp (Caused by 
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001B072055B50>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made 
because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

Below is my code for server 1 where I route the request I'm getting to send_hashkeys() function which returns a JSON to server 2. Next, I make a request to get a JSON file from server 2. That's when the above exception is thrown.

```
@app.route('/')
def send_hashkeys():
    return jsonify(hash_list_dict)

@app.route('/s')
def get_file_path():
    path_list = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/fp')
```

Code for server 2 :

```
message = requests.get('http://localhost:5001/')
message = json.loads(message.text)

@app.route('/fp')
def file_path():
return jsonify(file_path_dict)
```

This is my first time using flask. Please point out if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure both servers are up and running? You should note that server 2 requires something to be running on port 5001 at startup time (if you haven't redacted important bits of your code).

Comment: @AKX yes,both are up and running. first I'm starting the server 1 on port 5001. I'm also getting response from it the first time . the problem only comes when I send another request from server 1 to server 2.

Comment: @AKX I know where the problem is. I'm trying to give a request to server 1 before my flask app starts in server 2. that's the reason. is there any way to run a piece of code after my flask app starts?